# Operand data type time is invalid for subtract operator

Tags: sql-server

I am having an issue where this code is not working for me. It was, and everything is correct as far as I can tell, but I keep getting an error for the line. I understand that this is a duplicate of other questions, and I have searched through them, but nothing has worked for me

```
convert(time(0),(isnull(solver_endtime,'')-isnull(solver_starttime,''))) as solverruntime,
```

Here is the entire code in case I missed something

```
IF OBJECT_ID('staging.dbo.Log_Batch_Report_2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
merge into staging.dbo.log_batch_report_2 a
using 
(select batch,
    starttime,
    endtime,
    convert(time(0),(isnull(endtime,'')-isnull(starttime,''))) as totalruntime,
    convert(time(0),(isnull(solver_endtime,'')-isnull(solver_starttime,''))) as solverruntime,
    convert(time(0),((isnull(endtime,'')-isnull(starttime,''))- (isnull(solver_endtime,'')-isnull(solver_starttime,'')))) as non_solverruntime,
    to_time
from staging.dbo.log_batch_report
) b
on a.batch=b.batch and a.starttime=b.starttime and a.endtime=b.endtime
when matched then update set a.batch=a.batch
when not matched then insert (batch,batchdate,logility_up_time,starttime,endtime,totalruntime,solverruntime)
values (b.batch,b.starttime,b.endtime,b.starttime,b.endtime,b.totalruntime,b.solverruntime);
```

EDIT

This is what I get from the totalruntime line in this code. What is the difference between that and the other two lines?

[image]

Comment: Don't use basic subtraction. Instead use DATEADD. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: So I can use datediff the same as dateadd, correct? Also, dateadd seems to only allow for one piece of the date. How would I go about getting the full difference (hours,minutes,seconds)?

Comment: Well if you have the number of seconds it is just math to get the parts. Divide by  3600 to get hours, by 60 to get minutes. And take all the seconds % 60 to get the remainder. And remember that time is not a timespan, it is a point in time. So subtracting them is a bit strange. What would you expect the result of 3pm - 10am to be?

Comment: I would expect it to tell me 5 hours (00:05:00) in the same way that totalruntime piece (line above) does. But the datediff is working mostly. Now I have an issue of conversion from data type int to time is not allowed

Comment: Well again. Converting an int to time is a bit challenging. What time is 13? What about 214?

Comment: And what if that 3pm and 10am are not the same day?

Comment: I made an edit to my post. The picture is what I expect to happen, as it is happening for the totalruntime line of code

Comment: So like I said previously you need to use DATEDIFF between these two datetime values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am certain the DATEDIFF works, but what I learned was that my bigger issue was an error in data where STARTDATE was later than ENDDATE, providing a negative answer. So I needed to add a clause in there to only do my math when ENDDATE > STARTDATE

```
IF OBJECT_ID('staging.dbo.Log_Batch_Report_2', 'U') IS NOT NULL
merge into staging.dbo.log_batch_report_2 a
using 
(select batch,
    starttime,
    endtime,
    solver_starttime,
    solver_endtime,
    CASE WHEN endtime>starttime THEN convert(time(0),(isnull(endtime,''))-(isnull(starttime,''))) 
        ELSE null
    END as totalruntime,
    CASE WHEN solver_endtime>solver_starttime THEN convert(time(0),(isnull(solver_endtime,''))-(isnull(solver_starttime,''))) 
        ELSE null
    END as solverruntime,
    CASE WHEN endtime>starttime and solver_endtime>solver_starttime and (endtime-starttime)>(solver_endtime-solver_starttime) 
            THEN convert(time(0),((isnull(endtime,'')-isnull(starttime,''))-((isnull(solver_endtime,'')-isnull(solver_starttime,''))))) 
        ELSE null
    END as non_solverruntime,
    to_time
from staging.dbo.log_batch_report
) b
on a.batch=b.batch and a.starttime=b.starttime and a.endtime=b.endtime
when matched then update set a.batch=a.batch
when not matched then insert (batch,batchdate,logility_up_time,solver_starttime,solver_endtime,starttime,endtime,totalruntime,solverruntime)
values (b.batch,b.starttime,b.endtime,b.solver_starttime,b.solver_endtime,b.starttime,b.endtime,b.totalruntime,b.solverruntime);
```

This may not be technically correct, but thus far, it is generating the difference in hours:minutes:seconds format that I am looking for, even if the times are on different days

Answer (score 0):

To get the difference between 2 dates you can use following:

```
SELECT starttime, endtime, 
    Days = DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime) / 86400,
    Hours = DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime) % 86400 / 3600,
    Minutes = DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime) % 3600 / 60,
    Seconds = DATEDIFF(second, starttime, endtime) % 60
```